# AVAudioPlayer initialization error 1685348671. How to check whether file is valid?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer to play some ima4 files. The initialization of the player keeps failing with error code 1685348671 (dta) which according to the documentation means

> The file is malformed, not a valid
>   instance of an audio file of its type,
>   or not recognized as an audio file.
>   Available in iPhone OS 2.0 and later.

What I don't understand is how the files are invalid or malformed when I can play them with QuickTime? Can the file still be malformed? How can I check whether an ima4 file is valid or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having no probs playing ima4 files (in .aif) with `AVAudioPlayer`.

Maybe post some code.

Comment: The error code shows the file is invalid. How can I check whether an ima4 file is valid or not?

Comment: Try opening it with the AudioFileOpenURL, maybe it'll give you a more informative error.